# How do I format dynamically added footer columns of GridView

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

I've created the code below consuming a GridView from ASP. The grid works almost the way I want it to work. The new control automatically adds columns to the footer of the gridview and also adds 'save', 'cancel' and 'add' buttons where needed. There's just one thing I can't get work correctly. When the grid is empty a footer is added with columns and buttons but instead of the horizontal layout it creates the fields vertically. The cause is that the fields are not wrapped in 'td' elements. The fields and buttons all work but the layout is wrong. Any clues on how to solve this?

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Fortrus.Intranet.WebControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Produces a GridView with 'Edit', 'Cancel' and 'Insert' buttons
    /// </summary>
    public class CttGridView : GridView
    {
        public CttGridView()
        {
            ShowHeaderWhenEmpty = true;
            ShowFooter = true;
            RowDataBound += CttGridView_RowDataBound;
        }

        void CttGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[e.Row.Cells.Count - 1].Width = new Unit(50, UnitType.Pixel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This class is used to fill the different templates in the gridview dynamically
        /// </summary>
        public class StandardGridViewTemplateGenerator : ITemplate
        {

            private ListItemType Type;
            private DataControlFieldCollection Columns;

            /// <summary>
            /// In this variable the initialy defined columns are saved
            /// This is needed because we also add a column to the gridview
            /// </summary>
            private DataControlFieldCollection InitialColumns;

            public StandardGridViewTemplateGenerator(ListItemType type, DataControlFieldCollection columns = null)
            {
                Type = type;
                Columns = columns;

                if (columns != null)
                {
                    InitialColumns = new DataControlFieldCollection();

                    // Save the columns initialy defined for the gridview
                    foreach (DataControlField column in columns)
                    {
                        InitialColumns.Add(column);
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Method of the ITemplate interface is called when a specific template is needed
            /// </summary>
            void ITemplate.InstantiateIn(Control container)
            {
                switch (Type)
                {
                    // The tamplate for editing is needed
                    case ListItemType.EditItem:
                        CreateEditButtons(container);
                        break;

                    // A display template is needed
                    case ListItemType.Item:
                        CreateItemButtons(container);
                        break;

                    // A footer template is needed
                    case ListItemType.Footer:
                        CreateColumnControls(container);
                        CreateEmptyButtons(container);
                        break;

                    case ListItemType.SelectedItem:
                    case ListItemType.AlternatingItem:
                    case ListItemType.Header:
                    case ListItemType.Pager:
                    case ListItemType.Separator:
                    default:
                        throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }
            /// <summary>
            /// Adds buttons for the empty (footer) template
            /// </summary>
            private void CreateEmptyButtons(Control container)
            {
                AddButton(container,
                    id: "AddNewButton",
                    cssClass: "CttGridViewSaveButton",
                    commandName: "Insert",
                    toolTip: "Toevoegen");
                AddButton(container,
                    id: "CancelNewButton",
                    cssClass: "CttGridViewCancelButton",
                    commandName: "Cancel",
                    toolTip: "Ongedaan maken");
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Generate the footer controls from the initial columns
            /// </summary>
            private void CreateColumnControls(Control container)
            {
                if (InitialColumns != null)
                {
                    foreach (TemplateField column in InitialColumns)
                    {
                        column.EditItemTemplate.InstantiateIn(container);
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Adds buttons for the Edit template
            /// </summary>
            private void CreateEditButtons(Control container)
            {
                AddButton(container,
                    id: "SaveButton",
                    cssClass: "CttGridViewSaveButton",
                    commandName: "Update",
                    toolTip: "Opslaan");
                AddButton(container,
                    id: "CancelButton",
                    cssClass: "CttGridViewCancelButton",
                    commandName: "Cancel",
                    toolTip: "Ongedaan maken");
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Adds buttons for the (display) item template
            /// </summary>
            private void CreateItemButtons(Control container)
            {
                AddButton(container,
                    id: "EditButton",
                    cssClass: "CttGridViewEditButton",
                    commandName: "Edit",
                    toolTip: "Bewerken");
                AddButton(container,
                    id: "DeleteButton",
                    cssClass: "CttGridViewDeleteButton",
                    commandName: "Delete",
                    toolTip: "Verwijderen",
                    confirmation: "return confirm('Weet u zeker dat u deze rij wilt verwijderen?');");
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Adds a button to the container
            /// </summary>
            private static void AddButton(Control container, string id, string cssClass, string commandName, string toolTip, string confirmation = null)
            {
                ImageButton button = new ImageButton();

                button.ID = id;
                button.CssClass = cssClass;
                button.CommandName = commandName;
                button.ToolTip = toolTip;
                button.OnClientClick = confirmation;
                // Added blank image to prevent the default gray placeholder border
                // Image should be set using the background-image from CSS
                button.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhFAAUAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAUABQAAAIRhI+py+0Po5y02ouz3rz7rxUAOw==";

                container.Controls.Add(button);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create the child controls
        /// </summary>
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            ShowFooter = true;

            InitializeTemplate();

            base.CreateChildControls();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize the templates
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeTemplate()
        {
            TemplateField template = new TemplateField();

            template.ItemTemplate = new StandardGridViewTemplateGenerator(ListItemType.Item);
            template.EditItemTemplate = new StandardGridViewTemplateGenerator(ListItemType.EditItem);
            template.FooterTemplate = new StandardGridViewTemplateGenerator(ListItemType.Footer);

            EmptyDataTemplate = new StandardGridViewTemplateGenerator(ListItemType.Footer, columns: Columns);

            Columns.Add(template);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Here's the complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Fortrus.Intranet.WebControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Produces a GridView with 'Edit', 'Cancel' and 'Insert' buttons
    /// </summary>
    public class CttGridView : GridView
    {
        public CttGridView()
        {
            ShowHeaderWhenEmpty = true;
            ShowFooter = true;
            RowDataBound += CttGridView_RowDataBound;
        }

        void CttGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[e.Row.Cells.Count - 1].Width = new Unit(50, UnitType.Pixel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This class is used to fill the different templates in the gridview dynamically
        /// </summary>
        public class StandardGridViewTemplateGenerator : ITemplate
        {

            private ListItemType Type;
            private DataControlFieldCollection Columns;

            /// <summary>
            /// In this variable the initialy defined columns are saved
            /// This is needed because we also add a column to the gridview
            /// </summary>
            private DataControlFieldCollection InitialColumns;

            public StandardGridViewTemplateGenerator(ListItemType type, DataControlFieldCollection columns = null)
            {
                Type = type;
                Columns = columns;

                if (columns != null)
                {
                    InitialColumns = new DataControlFieldCollection();

                    // Save the columns initialy defined for the gridview
                    foreach (DataControlField column in columns)
                    {
                        InitialColumns.Add(column);
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Method of the ITemplate interface is called when a specific template is needed
            /// </summary>
            void ITemplate.InstantiateIn(Control container)
            {
                switch (Type)
                {
                    // The tamplate for editing is needed
                    case ListItemType.EditItem:
                        CreateEditButtons(container);
                        break;

                    // A display template is needed
                    case ListItemType.Item:
                        CreateItemButtons(container);
                        break;

                    // A footer template is needed
                    case ListItemType.Footer:
                        CreateColumnControls(container);
                        break;

                    case ListItemType.SelectedItem:
                    case ListItemType.AlternatingItem:
                    case ListItemType.Header:
                    case ListItemType.Pager:
                    case ListItemType.Separator:
                    default:
                        throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Generate the footer controls from the initial columns
            /// </summary>
            private void CreateColumnControls(Control container)
            {
                if (InitialColumns != null)
                {
                    TableRow row = new TableRow();

                    foreach (TemplateField column in InitialColumns)
                    {
                        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                        row.Controls.Add(cell);
                        column.EditItemTemplate.InstantiateIn(cell);
                    }

                    CreateInsertButtons(row);

                    container.Controls.Add(row);
                }
                else
                {
                    CreateInsertButtons(container);
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Adds buttons for the empty (footer) template
            /// </summary>
            private void CreateInsertButtons(Control container)
            {
                Control control = container;

                if (container is TableRow)
                {
                    control = new TableCell();
                    container.Controls.Add(control);
                }

                AddButton(control,
                    id: "AddNewButton",
                    cssClass: "CttGridViewSaveButton",
                    commandName: "Insert",
                    toolTip: "Toevoegen");

                AddButton(control,
                    id: "CancelNewButton",
                    cssClass: "CttGridViewCancelButton",
                    commandName: "Cancel",
                    toolTip: "Ongedaan maken");
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Adds buttons for the Edit template
            /// </summary>
            private void CreateEditButtons(Control container)
            {
                AddButton(container,
                    id: "SaveButton",
                    cssClass: "CttGridViewSaveButton",
                    commandName: "Update",
                    toolTip: "Opslaan");
                AddButton(container,
                    id: "CancelButton",
                    cssClass: "CttGridViewCancelButton",
                    commandName: "Cancel",
                    toolTip: "Ongedaan maken");
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Adds buttons for the (display) item template
            /// </summary>
            private void CreateItemButtons(Control container)
            {
                AddButton(container,
                    id: "EditButton",
                    cssClass: "CttGridViewEditButton",
                    commandName: "Edit",
                    toolTip: "Bewerken");
                AddButton(container,
                    id: "DeleteButton",
                    cssClass: "CttGridViewDeleteButton",
                    commandName: "Delete",
                    toolTip: "Verwijderen",
                    confirmation: "return confirm('Weet u zeker dat u deze rij wilt verwijderen?');");
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Adds a button to the container
            /// </summary>
            private static void AddButton(Control container, string id, string cssClass, string commandName, string toolTip, string confirmation = null)
            {
                ImageButton button = new ImageButton();

                button.ID = id;
                button.CssClass = cssClass;
                button.CommandName = commandName;
                button.ToolTip = toolTip;
                button.OnClientClick = confirmation;
                // Added blank image to prevent the default gray placeholder border
                // Image should be set using the background-image from CSS
                button.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhFAAUAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAUABQAAAIRhI+py+0Po5y02ouz3rz7rxUAOw==";

                container.Controls.Add(button);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create the child controls
        /// </summary>
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            ShowFooter = true;

            InitializeTemplate();

            base.CreateChildControls();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize the templates
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeTemplate()
        {
            TemplateField template = new TemplateField();

            template.ItemTemplate = new StandardGridViewTemplateGenerator(ListItemType.Item);
            template.EditItemTemplate = new StandardGridViewTemplateGenerator(ListItemType.EditItem);
            template.FooterTemplate = new StandardGridViewTemplateGenerator(ListItemType.Footer);

            EmptyDataTemplate = new StandardGridViewTemplateGenerator(ListItemType.Footer, columns: Columns);

            Columns.Add(template);
        }
    }
}
```